# The *NEW* Facebook 'Post Search API'

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This may look like an old question but is actually a new one (in other words, I'm aware they deprecated the "old" Post Search).

According to this [source](http://techcrunch.com/2014/12/08/facebook-keyword-search/) Facebook has now made it possible to search for Posts using the standard "Facebook Search" and I'm wondering if can I access this through the Graph API (and how)? Also where is the source of the article I mentioned? Where does Facebook announce this feature?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The Graph Search is not available via the API, so there is no possibility to use the new Post Search - at least not right now. But since they deprecated the Public Post Search, i don´t think there are any plans to implement it again.

Comment: Okay thank you for clarifying that. I did not know that the Graph Search is not available through the API (although one is able to retrieve some similar info through the API).